# Refused to execute as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type

Tags: scripts, mime-types

We added an external script in the body tag of our (dev) website https://zonnebeke.reclamebureau-simplify.be/zonnebeke2022/. However, when checking the console, I see the error message:

> Refused to execute as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type

Any idea if this has to do with Wordpress, or another setting of our website, or how we can solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: It’s likely not related to WordPress. It’s a combination of your server configuration and the external script. I would start by asking the script developer for assistance.

Comment: I visited the site and could not reproduce the problem, did you resolve this since you wrote the question? Is there any more information? Which browser did you test with? I see several items have a HTTP 400 error related to some sort of embed endpoint but no references to script execution or external scripts

Comment: The error in question is, I think, browser related.  I see that notice in some browsers but not others and thus far it has been inconsequential.  I believe it's Safari that most frequently triggers it for me.  Something about external scripts and the way they're being served seems to trigger it.